# Display tags associated to custom post type

Tags: wordpress, filter, tags

I have a page displaying first 10 posts for my custom post type 'tips'. I would like to display all tags associated to the cpt tips. But get_terms only appears to work on the single.php for a post and not on the main page. I have tried wp_word_cloud but this pulls in all tags within my site.

Is there a way to either:

1. Pass an $args to filter wp_word_cloud for the cpt tips
2. Display tags associated to a cpt on a page displaying multiple posts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo the_tags();
```

It should work on archive if that's what you mean by main page. 
[More info here in codex:](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags)

Comment: Hey Buddy,

Its a template page. I had this before but it only appears to be pulling in tags from one of the posts and not all ?

Comment: Are you sure you're placing it "inside" your loop. If you're getting all your post ids, you should get all the associated tags with that.

Comment: I need it out side the loop if possible?

Comment: That would never work as you need to access each post's info.

Comment: Ok thank  you bklybM, so there is no way to query tags by custom post type tips?

Best

leodw

Comment: Outside the loop you can use <?php wp_tag_cloud( $args ); ?> but it doesn't take custom post as a parameter.  One solution would be to use a taxonomy on those posts and use the tax as the arg. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud